# Why tf-idf truncates words?

Tags: r, tf-idf

I have a dataframe `x` that is:

```
> str(x)
'data.frame':   117654 obs. of  2 variables:
$ text  : chr  "more about " ...
$ doc_id: chr  "Text 1" "Text 2" "Text 3" "Text 4" ...
```

I can't report it here, with `dput`, because it is too large. I'm trying to estimate the TF-IDF and I wrote the code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(janeaustenr)
library(tidytext)
book_words <- x %>%
  mutate(text = as.character(text)) %>% 
  unnest_tokens(output = word, input = text) %>%
  count(doc_id, word, sort = TRUE)

book_words <- book_words %>%
  bind_tf_idf(term = word, document = doc_id, n)

book_words<-book_words[order(book_words$tf_idf,decreasing=FALSE),]
book_words = book_words[!duplicated(book_words$word),]
```

Anyway, I noticed that some words appear to be truncated in `book_words`. For example:

```
             doc_id          word n  tf      idf    tf_idf
 792727  Text 33268     disposabl 1 1.0 11.67321 11.673214
```

I'm sure this is a truncated term because, if I run:

```
x[grepl("^disposabl$",x$text),]
```

I obtain no rows.

This ever happen to you?

Comment: I suspect there are leading spaces (typically `data.frame` columns are not unevenly distributed like that without some leading spaces). Does `x[grepl("disposabl$",x$text),]` (no leading `^`) find anything?

Comment: @r2evans: thank you! You are right! I obtained just 1 row!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your output, it appears that there is leading blank-space in the name. If it were just `"dispoabl"` with no leading/trailing blanks, I would expect

```r
            doc_id      word n tf      idf   tf_idf
 792727 Text 33268 disposabl 1  1 11.67321 11.67321
 ###              ^         ^   one space each
```

but your output shows

```r
             doc_id          word n  tf      idf    tf_idf
 792727  Text 33268     disposabl 1 1.0 11.67321 11.673214
                    ^^^^  four extra blanks
```

This means that your `"^dispoabl$"` is too restrictive. Try to filter (here) with:

```r
x[grepl("disposabl$",x$text),]
```

removing the leading `^` and therefore allowing something before the `d`. Alternatives:

- `"\\bdisposabl$"` adds a word-boundary, so `"adisposabl"` won't match but `"a disposabl"` will still match;
- `"^\\s*disposabl$"` requires that anything leading be blank-space;
- trim the blankspace with `x[grepl("^disposabl$",trimws(x$text))]`, where your original pattern would have worked.